# Mac OSX Catalina install pdo_pgsql extension for PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I have a laravel application that I've been trying to run, but I get the following error when hitting the database:

```
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (7)
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: unsupported frontend protocol 1234.5679: server supports 2.0 to 3.0
```

I'm running postgres 12.1 (have also tried with 12.2, no go), php 7.2.28 (have also tried with 7.4.3, no go). The stack trace also mentions a PDOException, so I tried using `pecl` to install `pdo_pgsql`, to make sure I have the needed drivers, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Build complete.
Don't forget to run 'make test'.

running: make INSTALL_ROOT="/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-bowmanLwaFvm/install-PDO-1.0.3" install
Installing shared extensions:     /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-bowmanLwaFvm/install-PDO-1.0.3/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.2/7.2.28/pecl/20170718/
cp: modules/*: No such file or directory
make: *** [install-modules] Error 1
ERROR: `make INSTALL_ROOT="/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-bowmanLwaFvm/install-PDO-1.0.3" install' failed
```

I've been fighting this for hours today, just to get this application to connect to the database and work properly. Searching around to try different things, like downloading the pdo_pgsql package and manually building it gives the same error.

Help?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem and it looks like your question has some views so other people likely are having the same problem as well.

Comment: Did you verify with `phpinfo()` or from command line with `php -m` if the extension is installed?